# Virtual School Network Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

So I am an IT at a small Jr./High school and our network for it is very sketchy. Everyone is running windows 10 on personal laptops on a secure network that I have to sign them in on. I'd also have to take the computer away if they break rules and go on certain sites, even with the web blocker we have currently. I wanted to make my job, and the poor sap after me, easier by creating a virtual school server that they have to sign in on to access the internet. This would allow me to add, delete, and block users to the internet, or thats the plan. I already have a diagram, but I need to know how to set this up. I have worked with Linux and Virtual box before, however, getting all the computers to use something like remote desktop to connect to a computer that has different accounts all at once seems a little hard. I know that it can be done, i just need to know how. Any answers would be nice. If you could also give an idea for a web blocker, preferably cheap/free, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a [Captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) software ? (I.e show a web page asking for login to users when they connect, like some hotel WiFi networks do). There's many software applications to do that, e.g. [Antamedia](http://www.antamedia.com/hotspot/), which also does content filtering. There's many other free ones too.

Comment: Yes, however, I need to be able to deny them internet, but they still need access to the intranet (e.g. file sharing, printer sharing, etc.). If you know how to do that with Ubuntu server version, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know of any specific software, but most captive portal systems can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I found that a good "**free**" solution is to setup a pfsense gateway, [installation here](https://www.netgate.com/docs/pfsense/install/installing-pfsense.html), and use [aliases](https://www.netgate.com/docs/pfsense/firewall/aliases.html) to allow all lan connections, but block internet to specific ips, in the lan firewall section as shown [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/65443/pfsense-how-to-block-internet-for-one-client). I also found that setting up an ltsp server, [instructions here](http://wiki.ltsp.org/wiki/Installation), will allow blocking the user from signing in as well, [by this means](https://www.linuxnix.com/lock-user-account-linux/). As for the content filter, [dansguardian](http://contentfilter.futuragts.com/wiki/doku.php?id=big-picture_installation_guide&DokuWiki=3c741e61ac94f1723efc42e72f5f2c71) will do with group specific settings [shown here](http://contentfilter.futuragts.com/wiki/doku.php?id=group_configuration).